# how to use jQuery so that value updates when new JSON is loaded

Tags: javascript, jquery, ember.js

Within my Ember Model when I load data the first time it works. But, when I perform a second load the value in my each statement contains the values from the first load. How can I fix this? I have a feeling there is a simple (and possibly even elegant) solution to this.

Here is my model:

```
Hex.Asset = Ember.Object.extend({
    id: null,
    assets:[]
});
```

and the problem is here:

```
  return Ember.$.getJSON("/arc/v1/api/posts/" + id).then(function(d){
     var data= d.post;
     var post = Hex.Post.create();
     post.set('id', data.id);
     // HERE'S THE PROBLEM
      $.each(data.assets, function(index, value){
          var asset = Hex.Asset.create();
          asset.set('id',value.id);
          console.log("here is id:" + value.id);
      });
```

First json:

```
{
  "post":{"id":1, assets:[{"id":23}]}
}
```

Second json:

```
{
  "post":{"id":1, assets:[{"id":25}]}
}
```

After second load outputting id of 23 for asset and should be 25.

### EDIT #1

After thinking about this, I can do the following:

```
post.assets=[]; // part added
$.each(data.assets, function(index, value){
  var asset = Hex.Asset.create();
  asset.set('id',value.id);
});
```

But is there a way not to set this this way?

Answer (score 0):

You should define the `assets` property in Post to a relationship:

```
Hex.Post = DS.Model.extend({
    assets: DS.hasMany('asset', {async: true})
});
```

Then you can do this:

```
var post= Hex.Post.create(d);
```

No need to explicitly name an `id` property, it is automatic.

EDIT:
Since you mention Model, I'm assuming you're using Ember Data, even though your code snippet shows you extending Ember.Object.  Are you using Ember Data Model?  If so, you should extend DS.Model as I have shown.

Comment: thx, not using Ember Data (and Hex == App). Sorry, should have mentioned that before. I get the point of Ember Data but as a first time user, I'd like to just stick native Javascript objects similar to discourse use.